# how to deal with the envelope[] data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The data collector sent a time series data to sql server 2008. In order to make the data table more concise, the time series was sent in the form of envelop[].
this is the data stored in sql server

[image]

My work is to sum READINGS column in every row, for example getting a sum of (0,18,22,28,...) in above table. If there is any function to unfold the data such as {envelope:[{0,0],...} in sql server?

Comment: please paste expected result and current result as text

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a parser UDF

```
Declare @YourTable table (Readings varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('{envelope:[{0:0},{1:18},{2:22},{3:28},]}'),
('{envelope:[{0:0},{1:12},{2:17},{3:24},]}')

Select A.*
      ,B.Total 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Total = sum(cast(Substring(Key_Value,1,charindex('}',Key_Value)-1) as int)) from  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Readings,':') where ISNUMERIC(left(Key_Value,1))=1 ) B
```

Returns

```
Readings                                    Total
{envelope:[{0:0},{1:18},{2:22},{3:28},]}    68
{envelope:[{0:0},{1:12},{2:17},{3:24},]}    53
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: Thank your advise. There are still some questions to ask:1 what's the data type of Readings in my table? xml?2 could you provide some articles or blog about dealing with my problem or such data {envelope:[{0:0},{1:18},{2:22},{3:28},]}. Thanks again

Comment: @wikichung  1) I defined the sample data as varchar(50) could be anything  2) the XML is in the UDF.  This is the most efficient way of parsing a string.  It is very powerful and flexible... trust me you'll dig it.